# TI TM4C1294XL Programming Issue

Tags: microcontroller, texas-instruments, keil

I am working on a TI's TM4C1294XL LaunchPad with KEIL and I had a problem at the begining. I installed all the drivers for both USB and KEIL then I succesfully upload TI's blinky example to board it worked without a problem. After that I add some very basic code, in the default program it only blinks the PN0 user LED and I add some code to blink PN1 additionally but nothing has changed. PN0 LED still blinking but PN1 is not. I tried to blink other onboard LEDS PF0, PF4 but the result is same.  Here is the code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "driverlib/debug.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"

/**
  * @brief  Program main function
  * @param  void    
  * @retval none
  */
int main(void)
{
    volatile uint32_t ui32Loop;

        /* Enable PORTN peripheral access */
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPION);

    /* Check if the peripheral access is enabled. */
    while(!SysCtlPeripheralReady(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPION))
    {
    }

    /* Enable the GPIO pin for the LEDS (PN0, PN1).  Set the direction as output, and
       enable the GPIO pin for digital function. */
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);     
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1);

    while(1)
    { 
        /* Turn on the LEDS. */
        GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0, 0x01);        
        GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1, 0x01);

        /* Delay for a bit. */       
        for(ui32Loop = 0; ui32Loop < 1200000; ui32Loop++)
        {
        }

        /* Turn off the LEDS. */
        GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0, 0x00);
        GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1, 0x00);

        /* Delay for a bit. */   
        for(ui32Loop = 0; ui32Loop < 1200000; ui32Loop++)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I have been working on ST's microcontrollers for over 2 years but I never have that kind of problem. Is it possible to problem caused by some write protection feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the way how *driverlib*  `GPIOPinWrite` function works.

```
void GPIOPinWrite(uint32_t ui32Port, uint8_t ui8Pins, uint8_t ui8Val)
```

- ui32Port is the base address of the GPIO port.
- ui8Pins is the bit-packed representation of the pin(s).
- ui8Val is the value to write to the pin(s).

The **ui8Val** is the value that will be written to the port pins that are selected by the **ui8Pins**, not to the one specific pin. Thus your code will work if you rewrite it in the following way:

```
// Turn on the LEDs.
GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, (GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1), (GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1));
// Turn off the LEDs.
GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1, 0x00);
```